# OUTER JOIN with NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm using Postgresql and have two tables like the following:

```
Nodes             Node_Properties
-----             ---------------
id                id
attr1             name
attr2             value
```

Data in Node Properties table looks like:

```
id       name     value
----     ----     -----
1465     car      2
1465     boat     1
```

If there is not a bike property associated with the id, I want to return blank.

```
select p.value, n*  from nodes n
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN node_properties p on n.id=p.id
  where p.name = 'bike';
```

returns nothing.

```
select p.value, n*  from nodes n
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN node_properties p on n.id=p.id;
```

returns

```
2   1465  attr1   attr2
1   1465  attr1   attr2
```

I am expecting the result:

```
-   1465  attr1   attr2
where '-' == empty
```

Comment: Do you have a record in `node_properties` with a `name` of `bike`? Are you sure?

Comment: No.  The idea is that when a record for  'bike' doesn't exist for the node_properties, I want to return an empty value in the first column.

Comment: How would it know to get 1465 n.id for that non-existent bike entry from the nodes table?

Comment: n.id 1465 has no record corresponding to bike, other id's will have the bike property defined.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please explain *why* you expect what you expect or we can't address your misconception. Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable code & smallest representative example input as code. For SQL that includes DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table.

Comment: Learn what OUTER JOIN ONs return: RIGHT JOIN ON  returns INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched right table rows extended by NULLs. LEFT JOIN ON returns INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding of what an  outer join/ where combination actually does. An outer join (left or right) returns the data on one side even then the data does not exist on the other. Nothing you do in the data that does not exist on either side to appear in the result set.  If you need a particular that actually does not exist you need to introduce it. I cannot think of any purpose behind it you can get what you desire as follows:

```
with np (id, name, value) as
     (select id, name, value
        from node_properties
      union 
      -- bike must appear in the output so generate a row if it doesn't exist.
      select null, 'bike', null 
      where not exists 
            (select null
               from node_properties
              where name = 'bike'
            )  
     )
select n.id      node_id 
     , n.name    node_name
     , np.name   properties_name
     , np.value  properties_value
  from np 
  left join nodes n on np.id = n.id
 order by n.id nulls first;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's vague fragmented descriptions of outer joins like the one here that lead to people not understanding them. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. (See my comment on the question.)

Comment: Thanks.  Exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `left join`:

```
select n.*, p.value 
from nodes n left join
     node_properties np
     on n.id = np.id and p.name = 'bike';
```

Comment: That only works for me when the record for bike exists.  It's not returning a record when it doesn't exist.

Comment: @GeorgeHernando . . . This returns every row in `nodes`.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @GeorgeHernando Gordon's answer looks right to me. If that is not what you want, please click [edit] and explain why not, and what your exact requirement is.

Comment: See @Belayer's solution.  That what what I wanted.